# Call dataframe from one R file to a second file

Tags: r

I have one R file with a function:

```
screen <- read_excel("Template.xlsx", 1)


screen_norm <- function() {
  screen <- screen %>%
    group_by(Day, Plate) %>%
    mutate(Normalization_Mean = mean(Normalization_Control[!is.na(Normalization_Control)]))
  return(screen)
  }
screen_norm()

data_norm_mean <- screen_norm()
```

I need to access the dataframe `data_norm_mean` in another R file. I know how to do it within the same R file but not another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `source` the file which has `screen_norm()` function in another file where you need the data. If the name of the file is `'file1.R'`, in another file you can `source` it and you should have the dataframe.

```
source('file1.R')
data_norm_mean
```

Comment: Thank you.! This worked great.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the object in your original R script

```
saveRDS(data_norm_mean, file = "my_data.rds")
```

Then import it in your second R script

```
readRDS(file = "my_data.rds")
```